The `\node [label={[label distance=1cm]\num:A}] {};` syntax doesn't work for small angles around 0,90,180, and 270
The \node [label={[label distance=1cm]\num:A}] {}; syntax doesn't work for small angles around 0,90,180, and 270. Is there a way to overcome this?
I would like to use angles such as 89 and 88.

\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,fill] {};
\foreach \num in {0,1,...,359}{\node [label={[label distance=1cm]\num:A}] {};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I was inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/724636/319072 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/724375/319072 to use the decorations.markings tikz library like this:

\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,fill] {};
\foreach \num in {0,1,...,359}{\node [label={[label distance=1cm]\num:A}] {};}
\path[%
      decoration={%
        markings,% switch on markings
        mark=% actually add a mark
            between positions 1cm and 1 step 0.05cm
            with
            {
              \node[] (0,0)  {B};
            }
      },
      decorate
    ] (5,0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=360, radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

